# Simple while loop for every third numer

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Im not a php expert at all, and I am looking for simple php loop that will add 1 to every third number

This should look like this

111 222 333 444 555 666 777

and it will repeat 20 times.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: After 9, like 101010?

Comment: 111 222 333 444 555 666 777 888 999 101010. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++ )
{
    echo $i.$i.$i."<br />";
}
```

Comment: I dont down you but , , What you do if he wants 10times then you will add `$i.$i.$i.$i.$i.$i.$i.$i.$i.$i`..??

Comment: I used `$i.$i.$i` because of it's just three time. If he wanted 10 times, i would make with nested for or function or another thing. No need to force for 3 times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$str = '';
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 20 ; $i++) {
    for($j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; $j++) {
         $str .= $i;
    }
    $str .= " ";
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: You mean `for` instead of `foreach`?

Comment: Your result like `11 22 33 44 55 66 77`. Questioner want `third number`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$str = "";
while(++$i<=90) {
    $str .= $i.$i.$i; 
    $str .= " ";    
}
echo $str;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

better approach to use `str_repeat`

click [here](http://codepad.org/tQBcubTl) to look at demo

```
 for($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++ ){
    echo str_repeat($i, 4), '<br />';
 }
```